# solving the system

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, absolute-value

solve the system : $$ y+|x-2|=3 $$,  $$  |x+y|= m $$  graphicly when $m$ equals $6$.

I can easily (realtively) skecth the first graph , however, how the bloody hell do you sketch $|x+y|= 6$??

Answer (score 2):

You look for pairs of numbers $x, y$ such that either $x+y = 6$ or $x + y = -6$. Those pairs lie on two diagonal lines, one of which passes through $(0, 6)$ and $(6, 0)$, and the other of which passes through $(0, -6)$ and $(-6, 0)$.

Comment: thats very general how do I sketch it in practise?

Comment: John is exactly right and it is practical. $\left| x \right| = a$ means exactly the same thing as $x=a$ or $x=-a$, so the way to graph $\left| x+y \right| = 6$ is to graph both $x+y=6$ and $x+y=-6$. How is that not possible to use in practice?

Comment: I should add to my comment just previous that $a$ is a nonnegative constant or something known to be nonnegative--if a is negative the graph is empty.

Comment: so this is in fact not a function since it attributes to a single x two possible y values?

Comment: Correct: it is a relation, not a function.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the figure below, blue and green line shows the system $|x + y| = 6$ and the other two lines shows the other system. The black rectangles show the solution of the system. It is $ (2.5, 3.5)$ and $ (-2.5, -3.5)$.

[image]

Comment: i believe you can do the same thing by your hand or any other part of your body

Comment: the other answer just explains how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Just think about what absolute value means.

$$\mid x+y\mid  = 6$$
means that either
$$x+y  = 6$$
or
$$x+y  = -6$$
Just graph both of these functions as a single relation.

Answer (score 1):

We have that 
\begin{align}
|x+y| = 6 \implies x+y = 6\hspace{10px} \text{ or }\hspace{10px} x+y = -6.
\end{align}
From this we get that by isolating $y$
\begin{align}
y = -x+6 \hspace{10px} \text{ or }\hspace{10px} y=-x-6.
\end{align}
You should be able to sketch those two graphs by hand.